# How to send a signal to a running service on Windows and override default handling with c++?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, signals

I know signals do not exist on Windows, but the word was used for lack of a better one.

I have seen a lot of similar posts, but none of them propose a solution that does not involve a third party software.

I am curious if there is a way to send some sort of "signal" to a running Windows service with vanilla Windows command line tools, which can be handled in the service's c++ source code (which is multithreaded).

I have looked at `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` and `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`, but the CTRL+Break, CTRL+C, etc. only work in interactive mode with the running program in the terminal.  I am looking for something that I can open a blank slate terminal, and send a signal via a command to a running service.

C++'s standard signal library won't work due to it lacking support for multithreading.

Comment: Windows has a multitude of IPC mechanisms.  A named pipe might do what you want here, and then write a little console app that writes something to it that your service is looking for and understands.

Comment: Rather than outlining why your proposed solution fails, why not explain the *problem* you are trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable In case you missed the paragraph in the middle, it's right there.

Comment: Out of the five paragraphs, the *"middle"* paragraph talks about sending a notification to running (object) code to be handled by C++ source code. Doing that requires a time machine. To my knowledge, we do not have access to one (though that may change in a future past).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The builtin command-line [`sc control`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc742013(v=ws.11)) can send simple user-defined control codes to a service. The service's `Handler/Ex` callback can look for those codes.

Otherwise, have the service create an IPC (interprocess communication) server to listen to, such as a socket or named pipe. You can then have a compiled console EXE, or a Powershell script, etc connect to that server and send data to it as needed.

Comment: Yes it's possible to send user-defined control codes using the [`sc control`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc742013(v=ws.11)) command. See also `SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL`.

Comment: @rustyx thanks, I have added it to my answer